# Failed install Scrapy, ImportError

Tags: scrapy

When I input "scrapy" in windows cmd,
It prompts ‘ from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import x509 as rust_x509
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust:The specified module could not be found’

How to solove this problem?

Thanks so much

Comment: Don't use the windows app store version of python.  Download the latest version from https://python.org/downloads

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I downloaded Python from python.org/downloads, its version is 3.10.5, I see the same question in Github, your answer is the solution, they think, This particular problem (caused by python3.dll not being collected when using MS app store python) is fixed in PyInstaller 4.8. but I'm still trying to download PyInstaller 5.3, It doesn't solve the problem